# Не подключаются библиотеки в Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino

Я хотел подключить библиотеку "IRremote" для работы с инфрокрасным датчиком. При подключении заголовочного файла "IRremote.h" возникает следующая ошибка:

```
IRremote.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

exit status 1

compilation error: IRremote.h: No such file or directory
```

Если сменить `<IRremote.h>` на `"IRremote.h"` то ситуация такая же.

Как это исправить?

Пример кода, который я пытаюсь скомпилировать:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

#include <IRremote.h>


IRrecv irrecv(2); // указываем вывод, к которому подключен приемник

decode_results results;

void setup() {
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // запускаем прием
}

void loop() {
  if ( irrecv.decode( &results )) { // если данные пришли
    switch ( results.value ) {
    case 0xFFA857:
        digitalWrite( 13, HIGH );
        break;
    case 0xFFE01F:
        digitalWrite( 13, LOW );
        break;
    }    
    irrecv.resume(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: А как Вы устанавливали библиотеку?

Answer (score 0):

У Вас отсутствует это библиотека. Перейдите в Скетч/Подключить библиотеку и проверьте есть ли она в списке установленных библиотек.

Comment: В том то и дело что библиотека установлена и в списке библиотек IDE видит, но опять же при компиляции возникает данная ошибка